Does every $k$-connected chordal bipartite graphs contains $K_{k,k}$?
A bipartite graph is chordal bipartite if each cycle of length at least 6 has a chord.
We know that for a chordal graph, if it is $k$-connected, it must contain a $k$-clique. So for a chordal bipartite graph, if its connectivity is at least $k$, does it necessarily contain complete bipartite graph $K_{k, k}$ ? Currently, I have only explored this problem through a few examples. For $k=1,2$, it seems ok.

Where did this problem come from? It does look interesting indeed [I don't have the answer yet] but further context would be nice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_bipartite_graph mentions that "B is chordal bipartite if and only if every minimal edge separator induces a complete bipartite subgraph in B"

@Mike It comes from my research.

Somewhat analoguous to the vertex elimination order for chordal graphs, every chordal bipartite graph $G$ has a nice elimination order of edges,  which I now describe. In fact, this elimination order characterizes which bipartite graphs are chordal bipartite.
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $(A, B)$. An edge $ab$ is called bisimplicial if $N(a) \cup N(b)$ induces a complete bipartite graph in $G$. If $G$ is chordal bipartite, there exists an ordering $\left(e_1, \ldots, e_m\right)$ of $E(G)$ such that for all $1\leq i\leq m$, $e_i$ is bisimplicial in $G_{i-1}$, where $G_0=G$ and $G_i=G_{i-1} \backslash e_i$.
Using the above, we prove that if $G$ is a $k$-connected chordal bipartite graph, it contains $K_{k,k}$ as an induced subgraph. Take such an ordering $\left(e_1, \ldots, e_m\right)$ of $E(G)$, and let $a, b$ denote the ends of $e_1$. Since $G$ is $k$-connected, both $a$ and $b$ have degree at least $k$. By definition of $e_1$, $N(a)\cup N(b)$ induces a complete bipartite graph $H$ in $G$, and $H$ contains $K_{k,k}$.

Nice. It is right.
